# CORS Policy With Angular 11 and PHP

Tags: angular11

I Have An Issue With My Angular Project, The API was uploaded on a server and the front end uploaded on another server, everything works well except on my device.
You can Test that in this URL you can click on submit and see the response in the console
https://handcraftfgs.netlify.app/#/admin/login
and the response is that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtvzO.png)

Comment: You will have to allow the origin of front end url to your backend response headers

Comment: already added that and it works well except on my device

Comment: What device are you using? Android?

Comment: Did you check the response headers in your console?

Comment: I'm using laptop

Comment: cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
content-length: 15450
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
expires: Mon, 04 Dec 1999 21:29:02 GMT
pragma: no-cache

Comment: And where is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ? There must be this header also in response with value = <front end domain url>